# Difference between SYSDATE and Dynamic date

Tags: database, oracle, date-formatting, date-arithmetic

Actually i have an variable which contains date and it is dynamic,comes from java, i have to get that date and compare with system date and get the result in number variable

Ex:

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate)-TO_date('05/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') DAYS FROM DUAL;
```

and i ll use that number to validate other expression. my actual query should be like this

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate)-TO_date(VariableX, 'dd/mm/yyyy') DAYS FROM DUAL;
```

So here the VariableX contains dynamic date, the first query in which date i have hard coded is working fine, but when am trying to use with varibaleX its throwing error.

Comment: 1> What is the **RDBMS** product you are using? **SQL Developer** is a client tool, not the database itself. Looking ta the **DUAL** table, it seems you are using **Oracle**. But, you must include the relevant tags. 2> What is the error you are getting? Always mention complete details. Nobody can guess what's happening at your end.

Comment: What is the error? What is the value of variable `VariableX`?

Answer (score 1):

The variable must be a string literal, so that you could convert it into **DATE** using **TO_DATE** and proper **format mask**.

For example,

Using **SQL*Plus substitution variable**:

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(&date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') DAYS FROM DUAL;
Enter value for date: '01/03/2016'
old   1: SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(&date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') DAYS FROM DUAL
new   1: SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE('01/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') DAYS FROM DUAL

      DAYS
----------
         7

SQL>
```

Using **bind variable**:

```
SQL> variable dt varchar2(10);
SQL> exec :dt := '01/03/2016';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(:dt, 'dd/mm/yyyy') DAYS FROM DUAL;

      DAYS
----------
         7

SQL>
```